# Inferring a True Dual Port RAM (Xilinx and Intel compatible) in Verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx, intel-fpga

I tried to write my own true dual-port memory module, hoping that it would infer as a BRAM:

```
module dp_async_ram (clk, rst, rd0, rd1, wr0, wr1, in1, in0, out1,out0, addr0, addr1);
  parameter DEPTH = 16;
  parameter WIDTH = 8;
  parameter ADDR = 4;

  input clk, rst;
  input rd0, rd1;
  input wr0, wr1;
  input [WIDTH-1:0] in0, in1;
  input [ADDR-1:0] addr0, addr1;

  output [WIDTH-1:0] out0, out1;

  //Define Memory
  logic [WIDTH-1:0] mem [0:DEPTH-1];
  logic [WIDTH-1:0] data0, data1;

  //Write Logic
  always_ff @ (posedge clk) begin
      if (wr0 && ~rd0)
        mem[addr0] <= in0;
      if (wr1 && ~rd1)
        mem[addr1] <= in1;
      if (rd0 && ~wr0)
        data0 <= mem[addr0];
      if (rd1 && ~wr1)
        data1 <= mem[addr1];
  end

  //Read Logic
  assign out0 = (rd0 && (!wr0))? data0: {WIDTH{1'bz}}; //High Impedance Mode here
  assign out1 = (rd0 && (!wr0))? data1: {WIDTH{1'bz}};


endmodule // dp_async_ram
```

After running synthesis in Vivado, in the report says the following:

```
 WARNING: [Synth 8-4767] Trying to implement RAM 'mem_reg' in registers. Block RAM or DRAM implementation is not possible; see log for reasons.
Reason is one or more of the following :
    1: RAM has multiple writes via different ports in same process. If RAM inferencing intended, write to one port per process. 
    2: Unable to determine number of words or word size in RAM. 
    3: No valid read/write found for RAM. 
RAM "mem_reg" dissolved into registers
```

Number 1 Strikes me the most since this implies there is no way to code a portable true dual port BRAM. I was wondering if I am wrong with this or if I should just use ip generation. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think #1 means that you can't do multiple writes--just that you can't do them from the same process. Try splitting them up:

```
always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if (wr0 && ~rd0)
        mem[addr0] <= in0;
    if (rd0 && ~wr0)
        data0 <= mem[addr0];
end
always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if (wr1 && ~rd1)
        mem[addr1] <= in1;
    if (rd1 && ~wr1)
        data1 <= mem[addr1];
end
```

For more information on how to infer things in Vivado, look in the 'UG901 Vivado Synthesis' doc. For TDP BRAM, look under "RAM HDL Coding Techniques".

Alternately, if you don't mind being locked in to Xilinx, you can use the `xpm_memory_tdpram` module.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Process in this case is another term for an "always" block. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `mem` assigned by two `always_ff` should not be legal. The SystemVerilog LRM section 9.2.2.4 "Variables on the left-hand side of assignments within an `always_ff` procedure, including variables from the contents of a called function, shall not be written to by any other process.
Software tools should perform additional checks to warn if the behavior within an `always_ff` procedure does not represent sequential logic." Changing it to `always` technically makes it legal for a LRM perspective but synthesis tools typically require registers are assigned by only one process.

Comment: Good point, `always` is better. The Xilinx synthesis tool will be inferring this as a dual port RAM, and this is the template it prefers for that.

Comment: I agree @Greg: having two process (either in VHDL or Verilog) will make a multiple driver issue. Your simulator may warns you. Your simulation will fail.
If for some reason you compare your RTL design outputs with the FPGA outputs it will fail.

Comment: As you can see in the warning message above, Xilinx requires two processes to infer DP RAM.